# dynamically sized array in C using a function

Tags: c, arrays, memory, dynamic

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void dim(int*,int);
int main()
{
    int *array ;
    int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    dim(array,n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%2d",array[i]);
}

void dim(int *array,int n){
    array=malloc(n* sizeof(int));
}
```

why this don't work? i can't  do this?

I can't give a dimension to an array through a function?

I tried to find on Internet how this works, but i dint find anything so i prefer to post it here for a direct answer.

Thanks! and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 6):

The `array` in the function is passed by value, what you allocated in `dim` doesn't affect the `array` in `main`, it's memory leak.

Instead, pass a pointer to pointer:

```
void dim(int **array,int n){
    *array=malloc(n* sizeof(int));
}
```

And call it like:

```
dim(&array,n);
```

Comment: @exsnake If you need to modify an `int`, then a pointer to `int` is enough. But here you need to modify a pointer to `int`, then you need to use a pointer to a pointer to `int`.

Answer (score 4):

You're passing a pointer by value so dim isn't doing anything to it.  You need to pass a pointer to a pointer into your function like so:

```
void dim(int **array, int n) {
    *array=malloc(n * sizeof(int));
}
```

then pass in your array like so:

```
dim(&array, n);
```